# How to fix crash with error "Actions added to UIAlertController must have a title" when using Google SignIn?

Tags: google-signin

I get an exception in Google SignIn on older devices (iPhone 6).

The error is: "Actions added to UIAlertController must have a title"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. If your project is split in multiple sub-projects in a workspace, make sure the GoogleSignIn.bundle is linked in the root project.